# Running A Bookmarklet With Autohotkey

Tags: javascript, browser, autohotkey, bookmarklet

I have this neat little bookmarklet that refreshes the stylesheet on whatever webpage you are looking at without reloading the page:

```
javascript:(function(){var h,a,f;a=document.getElementsByTagName('link');for(h=0;h<a.length;h++){f=a[h];if(f.rel.toLowerCase().match(/stylesheet/)&&f.href){var g=f.href.replace(/(&|%5C?)forceReload=\d+/,'');f.href=g+(g.match(/\?/)?'&':'?')+'forceReload='+(new Date().valueOf())}}})()
```

I'm trying to write an AHK script to run the bookmarklet when I hit `CTRL + Q`. This is what I've got so far:

```
^q::
Clipboard:="?javascript:(function(){var h,a,f;a=document.getElementsByTagName('link');for(h=0;h<a.length;h++){f=a[h];if(f.rel.toLowerCase().match(/stylesheet/)&&f.href){var g=f.href.replace(/(&|%5C?)forceReload=\d+/,'');f.href=g+(g.match(/\?/)?'&':'?')+'forceReload='+(new Date().valueOf())}}})()"
sendinput ^l
sendinput {Right}
sendinput ^v
sendinput {enter}
return
```

It doesn't help that I don't know how to execute the bookmarklet without actually clicking it in the bookmark bar. The above codes selects the URL and pastes the javascript at the end of it - but this doesn't work.

Can anyone help me out?

EDIT: here is another attempt but this just searches google for the actual string instead of running it.

```
^q::
Clipboard:="javascript:(function(){var h,a,f;a=document.getElementsByTagName('link');for(h=0;h<a.length;h++){f=a[h];if(f.rel.toLowerCase().match(/stylesheet/)&&f.href){var g=f.href.replace(/(&|%5C?)forceReload=\d+/,'');f.href=g+(g.match(/\?/)?'&':'?')+'forceReload='+(new Date().valueOf())}}})()"
sendinput ^l
sendinput ^v
sendinput {enter}
return
```

Comment: You don't need to paste it *at the end* but *instead of*. I am not sure adding `?javascript:` ever worked.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you could use a browser extension which injects JavaScript into pages, using a modified version of your JS snippet to add a listener for the key combo `CTRL + Q`.

Comment: @VLAZ If I remove the `?` from the begining and delete the `sendinput {Right}` line it just searches google for the string

Comment: Yeah, more modern versions of the browsers tend to do that to prevent you from just pasting random JS to the URL. It's for protecting the users (supposedly). Bookmarklets bypass that restriction as a user has to add them manually and in some cases jump through hoops just to have them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing a bit of research, this may well work as a workaround:

1. Add a custom search engine in Chrome by right clicking the address bar, and clicking add next to "other search engines"
2. Name it something sensible and give it a keyword (in this case I used "refreshcss")
3. Paste the bookmarklet in the URL field and save.

Now modify the AHK script as follows:

```
^q::
sendinput ^l
send refreshcss
sendinput {enter}
return
```

This will take you to the URL bar, select your bookmarklet and run it :)

Comment: Note that you can condense this to one line of AHK code: `^q::Send , ^lrefreshcss{enter}`.